# Is there anyone who has ever implemented Ethernet MDIO(Clause 22 or 45) function through GPIO driver?

Tags: driver, device, ethernet, gpio

I'm using TI DSP Keystone II device for 10G Ethernet service.
The 10G interface is connected to Marvell 10G PHY device.

What I'm going to try is to use GPIO on the DSP device to access 10G PHY clause 45 management port, instead of using 10G MDIO on DSP.

Is there anyone who tried to do this? or even just implemented 1G/10G MDIO function in software?